# Android permission - can't connect to internet

Tags: android, permissions, android-manifest

I have problem. I had this manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />



<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="Svět Androida"
    android:theme="@style/MyMaterialTheme">

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="15"
        android:targetSdkVersion="22"/>
    <activity
        android:name=".welcomescreen"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">

    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".Cteni"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".MainActivity" />
    </activity>
</application>
```

and application worked fine but when I wanted generate apk. It says

> uses-sdk must be child of manifest

so i changed to this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="15"
    android:targetSdkVersion="22"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="Svět Androida"
    android:theme="@style/MyMaterialTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".welcomescreen"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">

    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".Cteni"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".MainActivity" />
    </activity>
</application>
```

I generated apk successfully but when I start app it stops, because it can't connect to internet.

edit:

link on manifest:

https://onedrive.live.com/prev?id=9637B6BAC6554B19%211922&cid=9637B6BAC6554B19&parId=9637B6BAC6554B19%21109&group=0&v=TextFileEditor

here is log with error:

```
08-04 11:15:02.966    2888-2888/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: simaproject.com.svetandroida, PID: 2888
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{simaproject.com.svetandroida/simaproject.com.svetandroida.MainActivity}: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
 Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
        at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1147)
        at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:418)
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:252)
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:215)
        at com.android.okhttp.HostResolver$1.getAllByName(HostResolver.java:29)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:232)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:124)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:272)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:211)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:382)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:332)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:199)
        at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:470)
        at simaproject.com.svetandroida.MainActivity.nactiData(MainActivity.java:78)
        at simaproject.com.svetandroida.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:57)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
```

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: I'm so sorry i can't paste it right here is link on my new manifest: https://onedrive.live.com/prev?id=9637B6BAC6554B19%211922&cid=9637B6BAC6554B19&parId=9637B6BAC6554B19%21109&group=0&v=TextFileEditor

Comment: What is the error? Do you have the logs?

Comment: I add it in edit. Sorry I forgot :)

Comment: Your using internet on the main thread (called UIThread). As Brayan said, you should used a thread like asyncTask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your error is not permissions, your error is this "Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException" that means you try do something in the Main Thread, if you consulting a webservices or something do in a asynktask

Comment: Thank you very much. You are great. :)

Answer (score 0):

The error message is pretty straighforward:

```
uses-sdk must be child of manifest
```

Your Manifest file is malformed and lacks `<manifest>`. See docs: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html

Answer (score 0):

if you use Android Studio remove this lines

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="15"
    android:targetSdkVersion="22"/>
```

because this appears in the y Gradle Scripts in build.gradle (Module:app)

Comment: add 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" /> and remove  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>